# FreeBSD raid issue

Tags: raid, freebsd, raid0

One of my machines (FreeBSD) has lost its raid (0/ stripe).

If I go

```
[root@torry /usr/home/bclark]# gstripe list
Geom name: st0
State: UP
Status: Total=3, Online=3
Type: AUTOMATIC
Stripesize: 65536
ID: 1006591079
Providers:
1. Name: stripe/st0
   Mediasize: 360102297600 (335G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 65536
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r0w0e0
Consumers:
1. Name: ada0
   Mediasize: 120034123776 (111G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
   Number: 0
2. Name: ada1
   Mediasize: 120034123776 (111G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
   Number: 2
3. Name: ada4
   Mediasize: 120034123776 (111G)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Mode: r0w0e0
   Number: 1
```

I see `State: UP`

if i:

```
[root@torry /usr/home/bclark]# mount -t ufs /dev/stripe/st0a /mnt/
mount: /dev/stripe/st0a: Invalid argument

[root@torry /usr/home/bclark]# fsck /dev/stripe/st0a
fsck: Could not determine filesystem type

[root@torry /usr/home/bc<br>lark]# fsck_ufs /dev/stripe/st0a
** /dev/stripe/st0a
Cannot find file system superblock
ioctl (GCINFO): Inappropriate ioctl for device
fsck_ufs: /dev/stripe/st0a: can't read disk label
```

If someone could help, it would be appreciated, of what the next step is, it would be appreciated.